# UserControl is way less performant hen declaring it in the XAML file

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls, reusability

I've been creating a WPF application, which contains a ListView, bound to a collection of strings. For each string it'll display the value and a button, containing an image and some text. To keep my code organised I've created an "**ImageButton**" UserControl so I can reuse this and make my buttons somewhat uniform.

However, I've noticed that using this **ImageButton** in the ListView is a lot less performant than defining the button straight in the XAML of the ListView. Am I simply misunderstanding something and making my **ImageButton** perform bad or is something else going one?

This is the XAML for the **ImageButton**:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WPFApp.Controls.ImageButton"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="100" d:DesignWidth="300" Height="auto" Width="auto"
             x:Name="self">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="DefaultImageButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2"/>
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="auto"/>
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Button Style="{StaticResource DefaultImageButtonStyle}" Command="{Binding ButtonCommand, ElementName=self}" CommandParameter="{Binding ButtonCommandParameter, ElementName=self}">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image Source="{Binding ImageSource, ElementName=self}" Height="{Binding ImageHeight, ElementName=self}"/>
            <Label x:Name="ButtonLabel" Content="{Binding ButtonText, ElementName=self}" Width="Auto"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Button>
</UserControl>
```

This is the code behind for the **ImageButton**:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace WPFApp.Controls
{
    public partial class ImageButton : UserControl
    {
        #region dependency properties

        /// <summary>
        /// Used to assign a command to the button.
        /// </summary>
        public ICommand ButtonCommand
        {
            get { return (ICommand)GetValue(ButtonCommandProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ButtonCommandProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ButtonCommandProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("ButtonCommand", typeof(ICommand), typeof(ImageButton), new PropertyMetadata(null));

        /// <summary>
        /// Used to pass a parameter to the assigned command.
        /// </summary>
        public object ButtonCommandParameter
        {
            get { return (object)GetValue(ButtonCommandParameterProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ButtonCommandParameterProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ButtonCommandParameterProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("ButtonCommandParameter", typeof(object), typeof(ImageButton), new PropertyMetadata(null));

        /// <summary>
        /// Used to display text in the button.
        /// </summary>
        public string ButtonText
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(ButtonTextProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ButtonTextProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ButtonTextProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("ButtonText", typeof(string), typeof(ImageButton), new PropertyMetadata(""));


        /// <summary>
        /// Used to display a image inside of the button.
        /// </summary>
        public string ImageSource
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(ImageSourceProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ImageSourceProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ImageSourceProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("ImageSource", typeof(string), typeof(ImageButton), new PropertyMetadata(""));

        /// <summary>
        /// Used to assign a button style from the outside.
        /// </summary>
        public Style ButtonStyle
        {
            get { return (Style)GetValue(ButtonStyleProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ButtonStyleProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ButtonStyleProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("ButtonStyle", typeof(Style), typeof(ImageButton), new PropertyMetadata(null));

        /// <summary>
        /// Used to control the height of an assigned image from the outside.
        /// </summary>
        public int ImageHeight
        {
            get { return (int)GetValue(ImageHeightProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ImageHeightProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ImageHeightProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("ImageHeight", typeof(int), typeof(ImageButton), new PropertyMetadata(20));

        #endregion

        #region constructor

        public ImageButton()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

This would be the code when I define the image button in the xaml, and is way more performant:

```
<Button Command="{Binding DataContext.OpenPlotSinglePointCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView, Mode=FindAncestor}}" CommandParameter="{Binding}">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Image Source="../Icons/Image.png"/>
        <Label>Show graph</Label>
    </StackPanel>
</Button>
```

I've tried moving the style resource to both application resourcedictionary and in the window where I used the image button, but the performance remains the same. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Creating a ImageButton is the right way, but you shouldn't extend UserControl. Instead create a custom control and extend Button. In the default Style you define your custom ControlTemplate. If you use the Visual Studio template everything is created for you (default Style is added to Generic.xaml). Because you are now overriding the ControlTemplate you can simplify the binding and use TemplateBinding instead of RelativeSource. This will also improve the performance significantly. Once you have converted your UserControl to a custom Button check again if the performance issues remain.

Comment: You could also just declare the Button in a DataTemplate resource that is used as ItemTemplate of a ListBox (which is the simpler base class of ListView).

Comment: DataTemplate is the way to go

Comment: Ok great, thanks for all the tips, I'll be sure to check these out and keep you up to date!